# Lagrangian formulation of Maxwell's equations with magnetic monopole

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, classical-field-theory, magnetic-monopoles

If we set $\nabla \cdot  {\bf B}=\rho_m$ where p<sub>m</sub> is the density of magnetic charges we lose the ability to write   ${\bf B}=\nabla \times{\bf A}$  . Can we get a new Lagrangian that leads to the new Maxwell's equations via Hamilton principle that is also invariant under Lorentz transformation? In this way we cannot introduce the ordinary 4-potential $A^u$ and i can't see how to proceed.

Comment: More on [Lagr. formulation of magn. monopoles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrangian-formalism+magnetic-monopoles).